# How to do unit test for Mui snackbar autohideduration using react test library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, react-testing-library

```
<Snackbar
  open={open}
  autoHideDuration={6000}
  onClose={handleClose}
  message="Note archived"
  action={action}
/>
```

Iam trying to do unit test case for snackbar . I need to do a unit test case where when i click on the snackbar it should disappear after 6sec . Iam trying to do unit test case autoHideDuration feature in [MUI](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-snackbar/). Iam using [react test library](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro/).

```
 it(" Should close after 6sec", async () => {
        const { queryByText } = screen;

         render( <Snackbar
          open
          message="Snackbar component!!!"
          onClose={onClose}
          testId="test-snackbar"
        />
       )

        const message = queryByText(" Snackbar component!");
        expect(message).not.toBeInTheDocument();
      });
```

Above is the test case which i tried

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
it("should call onClose when the timer is done ", async () => {
  jest.useFakeTimers();
  const testOnClose = jest.fn();
  render(
    <Snackbar
      open
      message="Snackbar component"
      onClose={testOnClose}
      testId="test-snackbar"
    />
  );
  act(() => {
    jest.advanceTimersByTime(2000);
  });
  expect(testOnClose).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Answer which i found is use act from react test library .